# Unable to connect to Jupyter Notebook from ec2-user console

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter

I am unable to launch jupyter notebook after configuring jupyter to use it through AWS EC2.

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-45-67 ~]$ jupyter notebook
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

Typing in the command "which jupyter" and "which python" prints out this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-45-67 ~]$ which jupyter
/usr/bin/which: no jupyter in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

[ec2-user@ip-123-45-67 ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

This is what is in my jupyter notebook config file:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' 
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply means that `jupyter` executable is not present on your machine with which you are trying to run the script.

You should try installing jupyter first.

Comment: Hey @shivams, i do have jupyter installed on my mac, and can launch jupyter notebook outside of the ec2-user console

Comment: @doyz Your mac and ec2 instance are 2 separate machines. If jupyter is installed on your laptop it does not mean you can run it on ec2 instance.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks

Comment: If this solve your issue, you can accept the answer so that this question can be seen as solved.